# Is it okay to have a slightly larger frame on a fixie?

Tags: bike-fit

I recently bought a  new bike frame, and I'm thinking if there might be some issues since the new frame's a bit larger than the old one.

The old frame was size 50, the new one's 52. I did some googling before I bought it, and some sites said that with my height (163.5 cm) anything from size 50-52 should be fine.

One of my concerns is with the standover height, as I have a 75cm inseam (barefoot), and the standover on the bike is at 76cm. With shoes on, my crotch is right up on the top tube. I haven't had any mishaps or issues with it, so I'm not sure if it's something to be worried about.

Another is that I might be putting too much weight on the handlebars since my hands feel numb after riding for a while. I'm using riser bars, paired with a 90mm +7 degree stem.

I'm not sure if the numbness has anything to do with the bike being too long, or I just need to use more of my core when riding (I'm not exactly the healthiest, hence I'm riding my bike for fitness).

I tried swapping out the stem for a 60mm one, and that kinda got rid of the numbness, but it felt too short and I felt cramped while riding it. I found myself wanting to stretch out more, if that makes sense.

Would using a slightly shorter stem (70mm I reckon) be a better option? I really like the frame, and wouldn't want to spend more money if I could, so buying a new frame is my last resort.

Comment: Dimensions for a frame or a bike in general are not set in stone.

Comment: Bullhorn or drop bars are often more comfortable than risers. Especially the super narrow or wide risers that are often on fixies.

Comment: The information you have given, but it's not enough. When it comes to comfort, "reach" is more important than stem length. Reach is the distance between the center-line of the seat tube to the center of the handlebar. You want the measuring stick/tape to be completely horizontal, so it's often necessary to visualize where the seatpost center-line is, and the measurement won't be very precise (nor does it have to be). If you'd like further discussion on this old question, please respond.

When discussing numbness, it's important to say *what* is getting numb.

Answer (score 2):

If the top tube is right up in your crotch when you're standing over it, then the bike is too tall for you, period. It might not be a problem when you're just standing there, or when you're in the saddle - but you bet it'll be a problem when you have to stop in a hurry.

The charts that map your height to frame size are useful, but only as a rough guide. That's because not all people have the same proportions. Two people of the same height can have different leg lengths or arm lengths.